# How can I format java.sql.Timestamp in a XML way using XStream?

Tags: java, xml, timestamp, xstream, datetime-format

I have some Java objects that I want to transform to XML. Some of the objects has a field `java.sql.Timestamp datetime` and I want them formatted in XML as datetimes is usually formatted in XML.

From what I know datetimes in XML should contain a `T` or a `Z` for UTC time. But if I use XStream the `java.sql.Timestamp` is formatted as `<datetime>2011-04-20 14:24:29.334</datetime>` in the XML.

Is there any way I can format Timestamps in a XML-way using XStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [Custom Converter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks! And `org.joda.time.DateTime` fixed all other formatting of the Timestamp.

Comment: Hi, is that possible to do some calculation in xstream before actually producing the xml output. For example can I subtract the date from current system date using xstream before producing xml?